# images size does not change on different screens Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have created a layout that looks the same in all screen sizes. The layout has lots of views that help me with creating gaps and placeholders for images.
For each image I added 3 sizes - X1, X2 and X3 in the assets folder.
But from some reason Xcode/Swift does not show them in the corresponding size. In all screen sizes they are located in their correct X and Y positions but their size is small. Any idea what I should do?
I am adding some screen shots so you can see what I am talking about.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistaken the sizes in the asset catalog for sizes to be used in the app. Different devices have different resolutions. Older iPhones and iPads have a relationship of 1 point to 1 pixel. Retina devices such as iPads and iPhones have 1 point represented by 2 pixels. And the iPhone+ sizes have 1 point represented by 3 pixels.

In order to have nicely rendered not pixelated images across these devices, you provide your image at three sizes. The 1x will be used on older devices, the 2x will be used on retina devices and the 3x on plus size iPhones.

If you need to provide different sized images you actually need to create new entries for those sizes in the asset catalog, name them differently and load the ones you need to use at run time.

Comment: To be more precise: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions But indeed, we usually count whole numbers for iPhone 6/7 [Plus].

Comment: Indeed. It's not really 3 pixels to a point. Thanks for providing precision.

Comment: It does not work. I still see small images in all screen sizes

Comment: Are you adding and using different sized images?